# Hidden characters in Microsoft Outlook output causing PHP's json_encode to not work properly

Tags: php, json, outlook, whitespace

I've inherited a MySQL DB that contains email subjects and message bodies generated in Microsoft Outlook (both Windows and Mac OS X versions).
When I attempt to use PHP to pull the message bodies from the DB and then run `json_encode` on them, the JSON has a number of (non-escaped) newlines within it, thus invalidating the output.

I had never seen this before, but upon further investigation, I realized that every instance of a newline was between a `<style>` tag and a `</style>` tag that (seemingly) had nothing between them other than a newline.

I then ran `preg_match` to capture the whitespace/newlines between one set of `style` tags. Upon doing that and running `strlen` on the results, I got back the number `2460`.

I then looped through each character in the captured "whitespace" and attempted to output them. At first, I only saw whitespace, but when I added `"\n"` between each character, then I suddenly saw the following output (minus some potential leading and trailing whitespace):

```
<
!
-
-



/
*

F
o
n
t

D
e
f
i
n
i
t
i
o
n
s

*
/



@
f
o
n
t
-
f
a
c
e




{
f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
H
e
l
v
e
t
i
c
a
;




p
a
n
o
s
e
-
1
:
2

1
1

6

4

2

2

2

2

2

4
;
}



@
f
o
n
t
-
f
a
c
e




{
f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
H
e
l
v
e
t
i
c
a
;




p
a
n
o
s
e
-
1
:
2

1
1

6

4

2

2

2

2

2

4
;
}



@
f
o
n
t
-
f
a
c
e




{
f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
C
a
l
i
b
r
i
;




p
a
n
o
s
e
-
1
:
2

1
5

5

2

2

2

4

3

2

4
;
}



@
f
o
n
t
-
f
a
c
e




{
f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
T
a
h
o
m
a
;




p
a
n
o
s
e
-
1
:
2

1
1

6

4

3

5

4

4

2

4
;
}



@
f
o
n
t
-
f
a
c
e




{
f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
C
o
n
s
o
l
a
s
;




p
a
n
o
s
e
-
1
:
2

1
1

6

9

2

2

4

3

2

4
;
}



/
*

S
t
y
l
e

D
e
f
i
n
i
t
i
o
n
s

*
/



p
.
M
s
o
N
o
r
m
a
l
,

l
i
.
M
s
o
N
o
r
m
a
l
,

d
i
v
.
M
s
o
N
o
r
m
a
l




{
m
a
r
g
i
n
:
0
i
n
;




m
a
r
g
i
n
-
b
o
t
t
o
m
:
.
0
0
0
1
p
t
;




f
o
n
t
-
s
i
z
e
:
1
2
.
0
p
t
;




f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
"
T
i
m
e
s

N
e
w

R
o
m
a
n
"
,
"
s
e
r
i
f
"
;
}



a
:
l
i
n
k
,

s
p
a
n
.
M
s
o
H
y
p
e
r
l
i
n
k




{
m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
p
r
i
o
r
i
t
y
:
9
9
;




c
o
l
o
r
:
b
l
u
e
;




t
e
x
t
-
d
e
c
o
r
a
t
i
o
n
:
u
n
d
e
r
l
i
n
e
;
}



a
:
v
i
s
i
t
e
d
,

s
p
a
n
.
M
s
o
H
y
p
e
r
l
i
n
k
F
o
l
l
o
w
e
d




{
m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
p
r
i
o
r
i
t
y
:
9
9
;




c
o
l
o
r
:
p
u
r
p
l
e
;




t
e
x
t
-
d
e
c
o
r
a
t
i
o
n
:
u
n
d
e
r
l
i
n
e
;
}



p
.
M
s
o
P
l
a
i
n
T
e
x
t
,

l
i
.
M
s
o
P
l
a
i
n
T
e
x
t
,

d
i
v
.
M
s
o
P
l
a
i
n
T
e
x
t




{
m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
p
r
i
o
r
i
t
y
:
9
9
;




m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
l
i
n
k
:
"
P
l
a
i
n

T
e
x
t

C
h
a
r
"
;




m
a
r
g
i
n
:
0
i
n
;




m
a
r
g
i
n
-
b
o
t
t
o
m
:
.
0
0
0
1
p
t
;




f
o
n
t
-
s
i
z
e
:
1
0
.
5
p
t
;




f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
C
o
n
s
o
l
a
s
;
}



p




{
m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
p
r
i
o
r
i
t
y
:
9
9
;




m
a
r
g
i
n
:
0
i
n
;




m
a
r
g
i
n
-
b
o
t
t
o
m
:
.
0
0
0
1
p
t
;




f
o
n
t
-
s
i
z
e
:
1
2
.
0
p
t
;




f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
"
T
i
m
e
s

N
e
w

R
o
m
a
n
"
,
"
s
e
r
i
f
"
;
}



p
.
M
s
o
A
c
e
t
a
t
e
,

l
i
.
M
s
o
A
c
e
t
a
t
e
,

d
i
v
.
M
s
o
A
c
e
t
a
t
e




{
m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
p
r
i
o
r
i
t
y
:
9
9
;




m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
l
i
n
k
:
"
B
a
l
l
o
o
n

T
e
x
t

C
h
a
r
"
;




m
a
r
g
i
n
:
0
i
n
;




m
a
r
g
i
n
-
b
o
t
t
o
m
:
.
0
0
0
1
p
t
;




f
o
n
t
-
s
i
z
e
:
8
.
0
p
t
;




f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
"
T
a
h
o
m
a
"
,
"
s
a
n
s
-
s
e
r
i
f
"
;
}



s
p
a
n
.
P
l
a
i
n
T
e
x
t
C
h
a
r




{
m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
n
a
m
e
:
"
P
l
a
i
n

T
e
x
t

C
h
a
r
"
;




m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
p
r
i
o
r
i
t
y
:
9
9
;




m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
l
i
n
k
:
"
P
l
a
i
n

T
e
x
t
"
;




f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
C
o
n
s
o
l
a
s
;
}



s
p
a
n
.
B
a
l
l
o
o
n
T
e
x
t
C
h
a
r




{
m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
n
a
m
e
:
"
B
a
l
l
o
o
n

T
e
x
t

C
h
a
r
"
;




m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
p
r
i
o
r
i
t
y
:
9
9
;




m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
l
i
n
k
:
"
B
a
l
l
o
o
n

T
e
x
t
"
;




f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
"
T
a
h
o
m
a
"
,
"
s
a
n
s
-
s
e
r
i
f
"
;
}



p
.
m
s
o
c
h
p
d
e
f
a
u
l
t
,

l
i
.
m
s
o
c
h
p
d
e
f
a
u
l
t
,

d
i
v
.
m
s
o
c
h
p
d
e
f
a
u
l
t




{
m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
n
a
m
e
:
m
s
o
c
h
p
d
e
f
a
u
l
t
;




m
a
r
g
i
n
:
0
i
n
;




m
a
r
g
i
n
-
b
o
t
t
o
m
:
.
0
0
0
1
p
t
;




f
o
n
t
-
s
i
z
e
:
1
0
.
0
p
t
;




f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
"
T
i
m
e
s

N
e
w

R
o
m
a
n
"
,
"
s
e
r
i
f
"
;
}



s
p
a
n
.
p
l
a
i
n
t
e
x
t
c
h
a
r
0




{
m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
n
a
m
e
:
p
l
a
i
n
t
e
x
t
c
h
a
r
;




f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
C
o
n
s
o
l
a
s
;
}



s
p
a
n
.
b
a
l
l
o
o
n
t
e
x
t
c
h
a
r
0




{
m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
n
a
m
e
:
b
a
l
l
o
o
n
t
e
x
t
c
h
a
r
;




f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
"
T
a
h
o
m
a
"
,
"
s
a
n
s
-
s
e
r
i
f
"
;
}



s
p
a
n
.
e
m
a
i
l
s
t
y
l
e
2
2




{
m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
n
a
m
e
:
e
m
a
i
l
s
t
y
l
e
2
2
;




f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
"
C
a
l
i
b
r
i
"
,
"
s
a
n
s
-
s
e
r
i
f
"
;




c
o
l
o
r
:
b
l
a
c
k
;
}



s
p
a
n
.
e
m
a
i
l
s
t
y
l
e
2
3




{
m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
n
a
m
e
:
e
m
a
i
l
s
t
y
l
e
2
3
;




f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
"
C
a
l
i
b
r
i
"
,
"
s
a
n
s
-
s
e
r
i
f
"
;




c
o
l
o
r
:
#
1
F
4
9
7
D
;
}



s
p
a
n
.
E
m
a
i
l
S
t
y
l
e
2
7




{
m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
t
y
p
e
:
p
e
r
s
o
n
a
l
-
r
e
p
l
y
;




f
o
n
t
-
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
"
C
a
l
i
b
r
i
"
,
"
s
a
n
s
-
s
e
r
i
f
"
;




c
o
l
o
r
:
#
1
F
4
9
7
D
;
}



.
M
s
o
C
h
p
D
e
f
a
u
l
t




{
m
s
o
-
s
t
y
l
e
-
t
y
p
e
:
e
x
p
o
r
t
-
o
n
l
y
;




f
o
n
t
-
s
i
z
e
:
1
0
.
0
p
t
;
}



@
p
a
g
e

W
o
r
d
S
e
c
t
i
o
n
1




{
s
i
z
e
:
8
.
5
i
n

1
1
.
0
i
n
;




m
a
r
g
i
n
:
1
.
0
i
n

1
.
0
i
n

1
.
0
i
n

1
.
0
i
n
;
}



d
i
v
.
W
o
r
d
S
e
c
t
i
o
n
1




{
p
a
g
e
:
W
o
r
d
S
e
c
t
i
o
n
1
;
}



-
-
>
```

Here is the output without newlines:

```
<!--/* Font Definitions */@font-face    {font-family:Helvetica; panose-1:2 11 6 4 2 2 2 2 2 4;}@font-face   {font-family:Helvetica; panose-1:2 11 6 4 2 2 2 2 2 4;}@font-face   {font-family:Calibri;   panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}@font-face   {font-family:Tahoma;    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}@font-face   {font-family:Consolas;  panose-1:2 11 6 9 2 2 4 3 2 4;}/* Style Definitions */p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal  {margin:0in;    margin-bottom:.0001pt;  font-size:12.0pt;   font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}a:link, span.MsoHyperlink    {mso-style-priority:99; color:blue; text-decoration:underline;}a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {mso-style-priority:99; color:purple;   text-decoration:underline;}p.MsoPlainText, li.MsoPlainText, div.MsoPlainText    {mso-style-priority:99; mso-style-link:"Plain Text Char";   margin:0in; margin-bottom:.0001pt;  font-size:10.5pt;   font-family:Consolas;}p {mso-style-priority:99; margin:0in; margin-bottom:.0001pt;  font-size:12.0pt;   font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}p.MsoAcetate, li.MsoAcetate, div.MsoAcetate  {mso-style-priority:99; mso-style-link:"Balloon Text Char"; margin:0in; margin-bottom:.0001pt;  font-size:8.0pt;    font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";}span.PlainTextChar   {mso-style-name:"Plain Text Char";  mso-style-priority:99;  mso-style-link:"Plain Text";    font-family:Consolas;}span.BalloonTextChar  {mso-style-name:"Balloon Text Char";    mso-style-priority:99;  mso-style-link:"Balloon Text";  font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";}p.msochpdefault, li.msochpdefault, div.msochpdefault {mso-style-name:msochpdefault;  margin:0in; margin-bottom:.0001pt;  font-size:10.0pt;   font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}span.plaintextchar0  {mso-style-name:plaintextchar;  font-family:Consolas;}span.balloontextchar0 {mso-style-name:balloontextchar;    font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";}span.emailstyle22    {mso-style-name:emailstyle22;   font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"; color:black;}span.emailstyle23  {mso-style-name:emailstyle23;   font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"; color:#1F497D;}span.EmailStyle27    {mso-style-type:personal-reply; font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"; color:#1F497D;}.MsoChpDefault   {mso-style-type:export-only;    font-size:10.0pt;}@page WordSection1    {size:8.5in 11.0in; margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}div.WordSection1    {page:WordSection1;}-->
```

After doing some research, this appears to be some styling markup created by Microsoft Office products (including Outlook). What baffles me though is why I can only see these characters when I loop through each character in the string and output them with newline characters between them.

What further baffles me is how to detect these characters and get rid of them so that the JSON output is correctly formatted without the newlines.

I tried running things like `preg_replace('!\s!', $email_msg_body)` on each of the email message bodies, but for some reason, the newlines between the `style` tags are still there.

Ultimately, I'm just looking for a way to properly format the JSON string so that I can output it. More than that though, I would like to understand why this is happening in the first place and how to prevent it in the future.

Sadly, because I inherited this DB from someone else, I have no clue how the feed that moves the Outlook emails to the DB was set up in the first place.
The DB is also `latin1` encoded. At first, I thought that the hidden string of characters might contain a non-valid ASCII character, but after running `ord` on each character in the string, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: It seems unlikely that `json_encode()` would generate invalid json. Can you post an example on for example http://codepad.viper-7.com/?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post an example of the JSON string, as it contains business-sensitive info, but I can ensure you with 100% accuracy that there are newlines not being properly escaped. It's interesting too, because all of the newlines in the actual email body (i.e., not within the `style` tags) are properly escaped and output.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was going on. It had nothing to do with the hidden characters MS Outlook was outputting at all.

It completely had to do with the fact that I was using the `ob_start` function with a callback function to format the buffer in a way so that any whitespace between two HTML tags was replaced with a newline character. This naturally caused newlines to be put in my JSON string after it had been formatted by `json_encode` because of the tags within the MS Outlook output, thus the issue.

Silly me!